# Should I avoid use of filters in servlets to check whether user is logged in

Tags: java, servlets, filter, servlet-filters

I'm developing my first Java based website. To check whether user is logged in when accessing profile or any other sensitive resources, I implement filters.
Because I found everywhere on the internet that we should use filters for login check (>as it seems like it's the "standard" way of coding).
But it only performs the following checks :

```
if(session.getAttribute("user")==null||session.getAttribute("user")=="")
     request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF\\webpages\\SignIn.html").include(request, response);
else
    chain.doFilter().
```

But to avoid "NullPointerException" I am already implementing the following "check" everywhere:

```
if(session.getAttribute("user")==null||session.getAttribute("user")=="")
```

So I don't feel that I should use filters for login check because anyhow it is increasing complexity of the code design such as putting extra efforts in url mappings etc.
So, Should I really use Filters "only for login checks"?

Comment: `session.getAttribute("user")==""` should be replaced by equals or better yet, `isEmpty()`

Comment: Yes, you should avoid it. You should use CMA and the security features in `web.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

It is good to have the session check implementation in the filter instead of implementing the same check in each Servlet/JSP. This blocks an unauthenticated user from accessing a restricted resource at first place.